AmStudio DIY Button Box questions for LED Buttons (noob)
I've been inspired by the Amstudios button box guide. https://youtu.be/Z7Sc4MJ8RPM?si=r_k9uTrmHQXXmteI. and another button box I found online that is way out of my price range. This box had a switch that turned the buttons leds on/off independently from the buttons actually being pressed.
As I am a newbie to electronics, and the amstudio guide being completely fool proof (cant wait to eat these words :D), I wanted to merge the 2 things for my first project into electronics. My design has 12 LED buttons. Please could someone verify my thought process and answer a few potentially stupid questions?
I don't want the LEDs to be on/off dependant on the buttons being pressed. I essentially want to use an additional latching toggle switch (not one from within the original 32 functions, it would be an additional but separate switch) to turn the button LEDs on/off, just like the above mentioned box I found online
Although not the cleanest, surely this can be done by running 2 usb cables into the box.... One usb to the Arduino as per the guide, and the other usb to my buttons LED pins only, essentially having 2 circuits within in the button box?.... One as amstudios, and one that's a simple circuit made of a power supply with multiple LEDs wired in series (or would parallel be better and why so?)..... Just like we learnt back in school when we used bread boards instead of wires, batteries as a "power supply" and a number of "light bulbs/LEDs"? (Really wish I listened more in school now!!)
With this in mind I have it in my head this should be simple. As I have a 5v powered usb hub with a spare usb cable to act as the "power supply" and the 3-6v version of this 4 pin button (https://a.aliexpress.com/_Ey5H1Az) to act as the "light bulbs/LEDs" of my school circuit example, surely I could cut the second usb wire and solder red to plus, black to negative to the "led pins" of my buttons, with the toggle switch positioned before the first led in series to control off/on and I should be golden?
Probably worth noting that my research so far heavily suggests that these buttons and this button box will work and function correctly without the need of wiring up the LEDs at all.... I just think it would look awesome to have them and to have the ability to turn on/off the lights dependant on night or day 
I'm praying I'm right and if so, what do I do with this second usb cables ground wire and data wire? I'm going to assume as the Data wire is not needed for the led circuit, I can simply tape it up out the way but I'm stuck on what to do with the ground wire. I assume if I linked this into the amstudios circuit via the ground pin on the Arduino, it would really mess up the matrix as the Arduino ground pin could receive some form of signals from the second circuit? Or am I over thinking it... as long as ground is wired to some form of grounding, wherever that may be it will be fine?

additional but separate switch) to turn the button LEDs on/off ... use the arduino to control the LEDs instead
